# problema com margem de div

Tags: html, css

olá, estou fazendo um kanban e estou com dificuldade de deixar as divs alinhadas. A div que tem mais atividades fica certa, mas as demais ficam lá em baixo.
[foto da tela](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO2mi.png)

segue o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/kanban.css">
        <title>Kanban</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style = "overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: visible;">
            <div style="border: 2px solid;" >
                <div>
                    <div class="container" style="width: 100%">
                        <div class="topo1" style="width: 14%;">
                            <h2>Segunda</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="topo2" style="width: 14%;">
                            <h2>Terça</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="topo3" style="width: 14%;">
                            <h2>Quarta</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="topo4" style="width: 14%;">
                            <h2>Quinta</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="topo5" style="width: 14%;">
                            <h2>Sexta</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="topo6" style="width: 14%;">
                            <h2>Bloqueio</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="topo7" style="width: 14%;">
                            <h2>Concluído</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="col1" style="border: 2px solid;">
                            <br>
                            {% for tarefa in tarefas_list_col_1 %}
                                <div style="display: inline-block; display: flex; flex-direction: column; min-height: 180px; width: 90%; _margin: 2px;  border: 2px solid #d7e04a; border-radius: 5px; _background-color: #d7e04a; margin-left: 10px; margin: 0 auto auto auto; ">
                                    <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 2px !important; margin-left: 5px; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                                        <div>
                                            <h5>{{ tarefa.titulo }}</h5>
                                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o">{{ tarefa.tempo_previsto }}</i>
                                            <br>
                                            <span>...........................................</span>
                                            <br>
                                            {% for obs in tarefa.label %}
                                               <div style="width: 90%; display: inline-block; height: 20px; _margin: 2px;  border: 2px solid #d7e04a; border-radius: 5px; _background-color: #d7e04a; display: flex; flex-direction: row; max-height: 20px;">
                                                   <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 2px !important; margin-left: 5px;">
                                                        <span>{{ obs }}</span>
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>

                         <div class="col2" style="border: 2px solid; position: 0;">
                            <br>
                            {% for tarefa in tarefas_list_col_2 %}
                                <div style="margin: auto; display: inline-block; display: flex; flex-direction: column; min-height: 180px; width: 90%; _margin: 2px;  border: 2px solid #d7e04a; border-radius: 5px; _background-color: #d7e04a;">
                                    <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 2px !important; margin-left: 5px; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                                        <div>
                                            <h5>{{ tarefa.titulo }}</h5>
                                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o">{{ tarefa.tempo_previsto }}</i>
                                            <br>
                                            <span>...........................................</span>
                                            <br>
                                            {% for obs in tarefa.label %}
                                               <div style="display: inline-block; height: 20px; _margin: 2px;  border: 2px solid #d7e04a; border-radius: 5px; _background-color: #d7e04a; display: flex; flex-direction: row; max-height: 20px;">
                                                   <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 2px !important; margin-left: 5px;">
                                                        <span>{{ obs }}</span>
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>

                         <div class="col3" style="border: 2px solid;">
                            <br>
                            {% for tarefa in tarefas_list_col_3 %}
                                <div style="margin: auto; display: inline-block; display: flex; flex-direction: column; min-height: 180px; width: 90%; _margin: 2px;  border: 2px solid #d7e04a; border-radius: 5px; _background-color: #d7e04a;">
                                    <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 2px !important; margin-left: 5px; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                                        <div>
                                            <h5>{{ tarefa.titulo }}</h5>
                                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o">{{ tarefa.tempo_previsto }}</i>
                                            <br>
                                            <span>...........................................</span>
                                            <br>
                                            {% for obs in tarefa.label %}
                                               <div style="display: inline-block; height: 20px; _margin: 2px;  border: 2px solid #d7e04a; border-radius: 5px; _background-color: #d7e04a; display: flex; flex-direction: row; max-height: 20px;">
                                                   <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 2px !important; margin-left: 5px;">
                                                        <span>{{ obs }}</span>
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>


                         <div class="col4" style="border: 2px solid;">
                            <br>
                            {% for tarefa in tarefas_list_col_4 %}
                                <div style="margin: auto; display: inline-block; display: flex; flex-direction: column; min-height: 180px; width: 90%; _margin: 2px;  border: 2px solid #d7e04a; border-radius: 5px; _background-color: #d7e04a;">
                                    <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 2px !important; margin-left: 5px; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                                        <div>
                                            <h5>{{ tarefa.titulo }}</h5>
                                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o">{{ tarefa.tempo_previsto }}</i>
                                            <br>
                                            <span>...........................................</span>
                                            <br>
                                            {% for obs in tarefa.label %}
                                               <div style="display: inline-block; height: 20px; _margin: 2px;  border: 2px solid #d7e04a; border-radius: 5px; _background-color: #d7e04a; display: flex; flex-direction: row; max-height: 20px;">
                                                   <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 2px !important; margin-left: 5px;">
                                                        <span>{{ obs }}</span>
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>

                         <div class="col5" style="border: 2px solid; white-space: nowrap;">
                            <br>
                            {% for tarefa in tarefas_list_col_5 %}
                                <div style="margin: auto; display: inline-block; display: flex; flex-direction: column; min-height: 180px; width: 90%; _margin: 2px;  border: 2px solid #d7e04a; border-radius: 5px; _background-color: #d7e04a;">
                                    <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 2px !important; margin-left: 5px; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                                        <div>
                                            <h5>{{ tarefa.titulo }}</h5>
                                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o">{{ tarefa.tempo_previsto }}</i>
                                            <br>
                                            <span>...........................................</span>
                                            <br>
                                            {% for obs in tarefa.label %}
                                               <div style="display: inline-block; height: 20px; _margin: 2px;  border: 2px solid #d7e04a; border-radius: 5px; _background-color: #d7e04a; display: flex; flex-direction: row; max-height: 20px;">
                                                   <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 2px !important; margin-left: 5px;">
                                                        <span>{{ obs }}</span>
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>

                         <div class="col6" style="border: 2px solid;">
                            <br>
                            {% for tarefa in tarefas_list_col_6 %}
                                <div style="margin: auto; display: inline-block; display: flex; flex-direction: column; min-height: 180px; width: 90%; _margin: 2px;  border: 2px solid #d7e04a; border-radius: 5px; _background-color: #d7e04a;">
                                    <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 2px !important; margin-left: 5px; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                                        <div>
                                            <h5>{{ tarefa.titulo }}</h5>
                                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o">{{ tarefa.tempo_previsto }}</i>
                                            <br>
                                            <span>...........................................</span>
                                            <br>
                                            {% for obs in tarefa.label %}
                                               <div style="display: inline-block; height: 20px; _margin: 2px;  border: 2px solid #d7e04a; border-radius: 5px; _background-color: #d7e04a; display: flex; flex-direction: row; max-height: 20px;">
                                                   <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 2px !important; margin-left: 5px;">
                                                        <span>{{ obs }}</span>
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>

                         <div class="col7" style="border: 2px solid;">
                            <br>
                            {% for tarefa in tarefas_list_col_7 %}
                                <div style="margin: auto; display: inline-block; display: flex; flex-direction: column; min-height: 180px; width: 90%; _margin: 2px;  border: 2px solid #d7e04a; border-radius: 5px; _background-color: #d7e04a;">
                                    <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 2px !important; margin-left: 5px; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                                        <div>
                                            <h5>{{ tarefa.titulo }}</h5>
                                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o">{{ tarefa.tempo_previsto }}</i>
                                            <br>
                                            <span>...........................................</span>
                                            <br>
                                            {% for obs in tarefa.label %}
                                               <div style="margin: auto; display: inline-block; height: 20px; _margin: 2px;  border: 2px solid #d7e04a; border-radius: 5px; _background-color: #d7e04a; display: flex; flex-direction: row; max-height: 20px;">
                                                   <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 2px !important; margin-left: 5px;">
                                                        <span>{{ obs }}</span>
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

segue o código do css:

```
div.container {
    height: 100%;
}
div.topo1 {
    width: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    min-width:14%;
}
div.topo2 {
    width: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0vw;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    min-width:14%;
}
div.topo3 {
    width: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0vw;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    min-width:14%;
}
div.topo4 {
    width: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0vw;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    min-width:14%;
}
div.topo5 {
    width: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0vw;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    min-width:14%;
}
div.topo6 {
    width: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0vw;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    min-width:14%;
}
div.topo7 {
    width: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0vw;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    min-width:14%;
}
div.col1 {
    width: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width:14%;

}
div.col2 {
    width: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width:14%;

}
div.col3 {
    width: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width:14%;
}
div.col4 {
    width: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width:14%;
}
div.col5 {
    width: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width:14%;
}
div.col6 {
    width: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width:14%;
}
div.col7 {
    width: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width:14%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tens que adicionar a regra vertical-align para top.

```
vertical-align: top;
```